Swagger UI and APIs of Other Modules Not Accessible in Multi-Module Spring Boot Project After Deployment
I am working on a multi-module Spring Boot project where I have configured Swagger to generate API documentation. The project structure includes several modules like client-management, institution-management, menu-management, and more. My main module is user-authentication.
Everything works perfectly when I run the project directly from IntelliJ IDEA. Swagger UI displays all APIs from every module, and I can also access them via Postman without any issues.
However, when I build the project into a JAR file from the main application and run that JAR locally on my Windows PC, I encounter the following problems:
Swagger UI: It only displays APIs from the user-authentication module. The APIs from the other modules are not visible.
API Access via Postman: The APIs from the other modules are not accessible either. Only the user-authentication APIs are accessible.
Steps I took:
I built the JAR file using Maven, and the build is successful.
When I run the JAR, only the APIs from the user-authentication module are available in Swagger UI and Postman.
In IntelliJ IDEA, everything works fine without any issues; all APIs are accessible and visible in Swagger.
Question:
Why are the APIs from the other modules not visible or accessible when running the JAR file?
Is there something wrong with my Maven build setup or my Swagger configuration?                         Here’s my pom.xml file from the main application (application module):
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneycore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>application</artifactId>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>client-management</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>institution-management</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>menu-management</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>moneycore-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>profile-management</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>role-management</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>user-authentication</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>wallet-management</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>user-management</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Swagger Configuration (SwaggerConfig.java): in user-authentication module (this module has properties , DB Configuration & swagger Configuration
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${app.client.id}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${host.full.dns.auth.link}")
    private String authLink;

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()))
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private OAuth securitySchema() {
        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList<>();
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all"));
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all"));
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("write", "access all"));

        List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        GrantType creGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(authLink + "/oauth/token");
        grantTypes.add(creGrant);

        return new OAuth("oauth2schema", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = {
            new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all"),
            new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all"),
            new AuthorizationScope("write", "write all"),
            new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything")
        };
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(clientId, clientSecret, "", "", "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, "", " ");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("MoneyCore Multi-module API")
                .description("")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("https://www.moneycore.com")
                .contact(new Contact("Tushar", "https://www.moneycore.com", "https://www.moneycore.com"))
                .license("Open Source")
                .licenseUrl("https://www.moneycore.com")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    // Added by Mamun // 2022-04-22
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    // Added by Mamun // 2022-04-22
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/null/api-docs", "/api-docs").setKeepQueryParams(true);
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/null/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/null/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources");
    }
}

The problem arises after deployment when Swagger UI cannot find or display the API documentation for other modules in the project. It only shows the APIs from the main module (user-authentication).
In the logs, it seems like Swagger is searching in the JAR files for the other modules but is not able to find the APIs. Below are the steps I took:
I have included the correct @EnableSwagger2 annotation.
I have added resource handlers and view controllers to handle Swagger's resource paths.                 1)Is there anything I should change in the configuration to allow Swagger to locate and display the APIs from other modules in the project?
2)Do I need to specify relative paths or dependencies in the pom.xml files for the other modules?
3)Could this issue be related to the deployment environment (Spring Boot multi-module JARs)? If so, what adjustments should I make to the configuration?                                         Additional Information:
Spring Boot version: 2.x
Swagger: springfox-swagger2 version 2.9.2
Multi-module Maven project
Steps I followed to create and run the JAR file:
1)I build the project using Maven, which creates a JAR file.
2)After the JAR is built, I go to the command line (CMD) on my Windows machine and run the JAR using the following command:  java -jar application.jar
Here’s the pom.xml from the user-authentication module:
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneycore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>user-authentication</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.moneycore</groupId>
        <artifactId>moneycore-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.0</version>
          <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
          <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.0</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
          <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
          <version>7.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>

Additional Information:
-The user-authentication module has a properties file for database configuration, while the main application and other modules do not.
-The internal communication between modules is happening through RestTemplate.
Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried multiple things, but nothing seems to work.
